# Getting the rows created before the selected one

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering about the best way to get the count of all the rows created before the selected one. Right now I have defined an accessor that looks like this:

```php
// In the model
public function getPositionAttribute() {
    return self::where([
        // Some other condition
        ['created_at', '<', $this->created_at->toDateTimeString()]
    ])->count();
}

// In the code
$model->position
```

It works correctly, but I'm worried about 2 things:

1. Is it a bad practice to call `self` on the model? Looks somehow off to me.
2. When called in a `foreach` this obviously generates a query for each element which is far from optimal. Is there any way to refactor this so that it can be eager loaded in a single query?

Bonus: I have totally discarded the idea of keeping a column with some kind of index because that initially sounded impossible to maintain, eg. when a record is deleted all the others should somehow shift position. Should I reconsider it? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that using self here is the "best practice" because that is how that keyword was designed to be used.

In regards to refactoring, i personally can't think of optimizing the query as is but instead you could create a function that preloads all the position then use it normally. Assuming your model has a unique key 'id' and you are passing in a collection of model then, you can try something like this:

```
public static function populateOrderPositions($modelCollection){
  // Optimize this query to include your "other condition"
  $idCollection = Model::orderBy('created_at') // this will make it in the order of creation
      ->pluck('id'); // this will only retrieve the id field

  // This array will contain an array with the model object ids as key and a numeric position (starts at 0)
  $positionArr = $idCollection->flip()->all();

  // Then just load all the position into the object and return it.
  return $modelCollection->map(function($modelObj) use ($positionArr){
      return $modelObj->position = $positionArr[$modelObj->id] + 1; // +1 because array key starts at 0
    };
}
```

You would also need to adjust your attribute code to use the loaded attribute instead of ignoring the loaded attribute like so:

```
public function getPositionAttribute() {
    return $this->attributes['position'] ?? self::where([
        // Some other condition
        ['created_at', '<', $this->created_at->toDateTimeString()]
    ])->count();
}
```

With these changes, you can then prepopulate the position then use it afterward without the need to query the database.

These code are untested as i don't know how your model and query will be structured and is more of an example. Also you would need to compare the performance vs your original code.